# C array sorting using qsort?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I have been stuck on this for a while and nothing seems to work.

I have a data structure:

```
DATA
{
  int size;
  int id;
}
```

And I have an array of DATA structures:

```
myArray = (DATA *) malloc(10 * sizeof(DATA));
```

Then I assign some test values:

```
myArray[0].size = 5;
myArray[1].size = 9;
myArray[2].size = 1;
myArray[3].size = 3;
```

So my starting array should look like:

```
5,9,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Then, I call `qsort(myArray,10,sizeof(DATA),comp)`

Where comp is:

```
  int comp(const DATA * a, const DATA * b)
{
    return a.size - b.size;
}
```

And trust me, I tried many things with the compare function, NOTHING seems to work. I just never get any sorting that makes any sense.

Comment: Can you post a full runnable sample? Devil is likely in the details you omit.

Comment: did you initialize other elements of `myArray`? or are you just assuming that the uninitialized values will be zero?

Comment: When allocating multiple elements, if you want to be sure that the memory is "zeroed" you'd better use calloc: calloc(10, sizeof(DATA)); malloc does not assure you to have them set to zero.

Comment: How do you call `qsort`?

Comment: @Teudimundo Why don't you make that into an answer instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my starting array should look like 5, 9, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

No, it really *won't,* at least it's not guaranteed to.

If you want zeros in there, either use `calloc()` to zero everything out, or put them in yourself. What `malloc()` will give you is a block of the size required that has *indeterminant* content. In other words, it may well have whatever rubbish was in memory beforehand.

And, on top of that, `a` and `b` are *pointers* in your `comp` function, you should be using `->` rather than `.` and it's good form to use the correct prototype with casting.

And a final note: please don't cast the return from `malloc` in C - you can get into problems if you accidentally forget to include the relevant header file and your integers aren't compatible with your pointers.

The `malloc` function returns a `void *` which will quite happily convert implicitly into any other pointer.

---

Here's a complete program with those fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {int size; int id;} DATA;

int comp (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((DATA *)a)->size - ((DATA *)b)->size;
}

int main (void) {
    int i;
    DATA *myArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(DATA));
    myArray[0].size = 5;
    myArray[1].size = 9;
    myArray[2].size = 1;
    myArray[3].size = 3;
    for (i = 4; i < 10; i++)
        myArray[i].size = 0;

    qsort (myArray, 10, sizeof(DATA), comp);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("%d ", myArray[i].size);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 5 9
```